# wpf Combobox border color on mouseclick

Tags: wpf, xaml, combobox

I have a combobox style.

When tabed to combobox the focus will work because of FocusButtonStyle, but I can't find out how to get the same border when user clicks on the combobox. It's like it dosen't get focused that way.

Tried triggers, but can't get it to work.

```
<Style x:Key="ItemStyle" TargetType="{x:Type ComboBoxItem}">
        <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels" Value="true"/>
        <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="true"/>
        <Setter Property="Padding" Value="8,8,0,7"/>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ComboBoxItem}">
                    <Border 
                        Name="Border"
                        Padding="2"
                        SnapsToDevicePixels="true">
                        <ContentPresenter />
                    </Border>
                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="IsHighlighted" Value="true">
                            <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource Interaction-Hover}"/>
                        </Trigger>
                        <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="false">
                            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{StaticResource Grey-7}"/>
                            <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource Grey-Bg}"/>
                            <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource Grey-3}"/>
                        </Trigger>
                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

I tried with trigger on style below, with is checked, but it only lasted for the click, and only for the smal togglebutton, tried the same on the one overlaying the textbox but it didn't take.

```
    <Style x:Key="ComboBoxButtonStyle" TargetType="{x:Type ToggleButton}">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ToggleButton}">

                    <Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" 
                            x:Name="border" 
                            CornerRadius="0,4,4,0" 
                            BorderThickness="0,1,1,1"
                            BorderBrush="{StaticResource Grey-Border}">
                        <ContentPresenter />
                    </Border>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>

    <Style x:Key="ComboBoxTextBoxStyle" TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
        <!--<Setter Property="Padding" Value="8,8,0,7"/>-->
        <Setter Property="Focusable" Value="False" />
        <Setter Property="IsReadOnly" Value="True" />
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
                    <Grid>
                        <Border CornerRadius="4,0,0,4"
                                x:Name="border" 
                                BorderThickness="1,1,0,1"
                                Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                                BorderBrush="{StaticResource Grey-Border}">
                            <ScrollViewer x:Name="PART_ContentHost"/>
                        </Border>
                    </Grid>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>

    <Style x:Key="ComboBoxOverlayToggleButtonStyle" TargetType="ToggleButton">
        <Setter Property="Focusable" Value="False" />
        <Setter Property="ClickMode" Value="Press" />
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="ToggleButton">
                    <Grid Background="Transparent"/>                    
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>

    <Style x:Key="FocusButtonStyle" TargetType="Control">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate>
                    <Rectangle Stroke="{StaticResource Default-Border-Brush}" 
                               SnapsToDevicePixels="True" 
                               RadiusX="4" 
                               RadiusY="4" />
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>

    <Style x:Key="ComboBoxStyle" BasedOn="{StaticResource Caption1}" TargetType="{x:Type ComboBox}">
        <Setter Property="Height" Value="35"/>
        <Setter Property="Margin" Value="16,0,0,0"/>
        <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Center"/>
        <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Transparent"/>
        <Setter Property="Focusable" Value="True"/>
        <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels" Value="true"/>
        <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="true"/>
        <Setter Property="ItemContainerStyle" Value="{StaticResource ItemStyle}"/>
        <Setter Property="FocusVisualStyle" Value="{StaticResource FocusButtonStyle}"/>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ComboBox}">
                    <Grid>
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition />
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="18"/>
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                        <ToggleButton  Grid.Column="0"
                                       Style="{StaticResource ComboBoxOverlayToggleButtonStyle}"
                                       IsChecked="{Binding Path=IsDropDownOpen, Mode=TwoWay, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"
                                       Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"/>

                        <TextBox Grid.Column="0" 
                                 Name="PART_EditableTextBox"
                                 Style="{StaticResource ComboBoxTextBoxStyle}"
                                 Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                                 IsHitTestVisible="{TemplateBinding IsEditable}"/>

                        <ToggleButton Grid.Column="1"
                                      Height="{TemplateBinding Height}"
                                      Style="{StaticResource ComboBoxButtonStyle}"
                                      Focusable="False"
                                      IsChecked="{Binding Path=IsDropDownOpen, Mode=TwoWay, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"
                                      ClickMode="Press"
                                      Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">

                            <Path Grid.Column="1"
                                  HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                                  VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                  Data="M 0 0 L 4 4 L 8 0 Z"
                                  Fill="Black" />

                        </ToggleButton>

                        <ContentPresenter Grid.Column="0" 
                                          Name="ContentSite"
                                          Content="{TemplateBinding SelectionBoxItem}"
                                          ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding SelectionBoxItemTemplate}"
                                          ContentTemplateSelector="{TemplateBinding ItemTemplateSelector}"
                                          VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                          HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                                          Margin="5,0,0,0"/>

                        <Popup Grid.Column="0" 
                               Name="Popup"
                               Placement="Bottom"
                               IsOpen="{TemplateBinding IsDropDownOpen}"
                               AllowsTransparency="True" 
                               Focusable="False"
                               PopupAnimation="Slide">

                            <Border x:Name="DropDownBorder"
                                    BorderThickness="1,1,1,1"
                                    CornerRadius="0,4,4,4"
                                    Background="White"
                                    BorderBrush="{StaticResource Grey-Border}">

                                <Grid Name="DropDown"
                                      SnapsToDevicePixels="True"
                                      MinWidth="{TemplateBinding ActualWidth}"
                                      MaxHeight="{TemplateBinding MaxDropDownHeight}">

                                    <ScrollViewer SnapsToDevicePixels="True" 
                                                  HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden" 
                                                  VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
                                        <StackPanel IsItemsHost="True" 
                                                    KeyboardNavigation.DirectionalNavigation="Contained" />
                                    </ScrollViewer>
                                </Grid>
                            </Border>
                        </Popup>
                    </Grid>
                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="IsReadOnly" Value="True">
                            <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource Grey-Bg}"/>
                            <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="False"/>
                            <Setter Property="Focusable" Value="False"/>
                        </Trigger>
                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

**Solution**

Added this to Combobox Template

```
<Rectangle x:Name="focusRect" 
           Grid.Column="0"
           Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
           Grid.ZIndex="1"
           SnapsToDevicePixels="true"
           Stroke="{StaticResource PrimaryBrush}"
           RadiusX="4" 
           RadiusY="4"
           Visibility="Collapsed"/>
```

and these triggers:

```
<Trigger Property="IsDropDownOpen" Value="True">
        <Setter TargetName="focusRect" Property="Visibility" Value="Visible" />
</Trigger>
<Trigger Property="IsFocused" Value="True">
        <Setter TargetName="focusRect" Property="Visibility" Value="Visible" />
</Trigger>
```

```
<Setter Property="FocusVisualStyle" Value="{x:Null}"/>
```

Comment: Can't you just trigger on IsFocused?

Comment: @GazTheDestroyer tried that too, couldn't get it to work

Comment: I see you are setting Focusable to False sometimes. That may be stopping it.

Comment: @GazTheDestroyer need to have it to prevent multiple tabsstops on the combobox

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `FocusVisualStyle` only applies when the control is focused via keyboard navigation. This is by design.

You could still create your own custom template to achieve the same effect though. In the below example markup, I have added a `Rectangle` to the `ComboBox` template and a `Trigger` that sets its `Visibility` property to `Visible` when the `ComboBox` is focused. You can edit it as per your exact requirements.

```
<ComboBox>
    <ComboBox.Resources>
        <Style x:Key="FocusVisual">
            <Setter Property="Control.Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate>
                        <Rectangle Margin="2" SnapsToDevicePixels="true" Stroke="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlTextBrushKey}}" StrokeThickness="1" StrokeDashArray="1 2"/>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
        <LinearGradientBrush x:Key="ComboBox.Static.Background" EndPoint="0,1" StartPoint="0,0">
            <GradientStop Color="#FFF0F0F0" Offset="0.0"/>
            <GradientStop Color="#FFE5E5E5" Offset="1.0"/>
        </LinearGradientBrush>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="ComboBox.Static.Border" Color="#FFACACAC"/>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="ComboBox.Static.Editable.Background" Color="#FFFFFFFF"/>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="ComboBox.Static.Editable.Border" Color="#FFABADB3"/>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="ComboBox.Static.Editable.Button.Background" Color="Transparent"/>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="ComboBox.Static.Editable.Button.Border" Color="Transparent"/>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="ComboBox.MouseOver.Glyph" Color="#FF000000"/>
        <LinearGradientBrush x:Key="ComboBox.MouseOver.Background" EndPoint="0,1" StartPoint="0,0">
            <GradientStop Color="#FFECF4FC" Offset="0.0"/>
            <GradientStop Color="#FFDCECFC" Offset="1.0"/>
        </LinearGradientBrush>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="ComboBox.MouseOver.Border" Color="#FF7EB4EA"/>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="ComboBox.MouseOver.Editable.Background" Color="#FFFFFFFF"/>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="ComboBox.MouseOver.Editable.Border" Color="#FF7EB4EA"/>
        <LinearGradientBrush x:Key="ComboBox.MouseOver.Editable.Button.Background" EndPoint="0,1" StartPoint="0,0">
            <GradientStop Color="#FFEBF4FC" Offset="0.0"/>
            <GradientStop Color="#FFDCECFC" Offset="1.0"/>
        </LinearGradientBrush>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="ComboBox.MouseOver.Editable.Button.Border" Color="#FF7EB4EA"/>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="ComboBox.Pressed.Glyph" Color="#FF000000"/>
        <LinearGradientBrush x:Key="ComboBox.Pressed.Background" EndPoint="0,1" StartPoint="0,0">
            <GradientStop Color="#FFDAECFC" Offset="0.0"/>
            <GradientStop Color="#FFC4E0FC" Offset="1.0"/>
        </LinearGradientBrush>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="ComboBox.Pressed.Border" Color="#FF569DE5"/>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="ComboBox.Pressed.Editable.Background" Color="#FFFFFFFF"/>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="ComboBox.Pressed.Editable.Border" Color="#FF569DE5"/>
        <LinearGradientBrush x:Key="ComboBox.Pressed.Editable.Button.Background" EndPoint="0,1" StartPoint="0,0">
            <GradientStop Color="#FFDAEBFC" Offset="0.0"/>
            <GradientStop Color="#FFC4E0FC" Offset="1.0"/>
        </LinearGradientBrush>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="ComboBox.Pressed.Editable.Button.Border" Color="#FF569DE5"/>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="ComboBox.Disabled.Glyph" Color="#FFBFBFBF"/>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="ComboBox.Disabled.Background" Color="#FFF0F0F0"/>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="ComboBox.Disabled.Border" Color="#FFD9D9D9"/>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="ComboBox.Disabled.Editable.Background" Color="#FFFFFFFF"/>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="ComboBox.Disabled.Editable.Border" Color="#FFBFBFBF"/>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="ComboBox.Disabled.Editable.Button.Background" Color="Transparent"/>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="ComboBox.Disabled.Editable.Button.Border" Color="Transparent"/>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="ComboBox.Static.Glyph" Color="#FF606060"/>
        <Style x:Key="ComboBoxToggleButton" TargetType="{x:Type ToggleButton}">
            <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="true"/>
            <Setter Property="IsTabStop" Value="false"/>
            <Setter Property="Focusable" Value="false"/>
            <Setter Property="ClickMode" Value="Press"/>
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ToggleButton}">
                        <Border x:Name="templateRoot" BorderBrush="{StaticResource ComboBox.Static.Border}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Background="{StaticResource ComboBox.Static.Background}" SnapsToDevicePixels="true">
                            <Border x:Name="splitBorder" BorderBrush="Transparent" BorderThickness="1" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="0" SnapsToDevicePixels="true" Width="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemParameters.VerticalScrollBarWidthKey}}">
                                <Path x:Name="arrow" Data="F1 M 0,0 L 2.667,2.66665 L 5.3334,0 L 5.3334,-1.78168 L 2.6667,0.88501 L0,-1.78168 L0,0 Z" Fill="{StaticResource ComboBox.Static.Glyph}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="0" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                            </Border>
                        </Border>
                        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                            <MultiDataTrigger>
                                <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                                    <Condition Binding="{Binding IsEditable, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ComboBox}}}" Value="true"/>
                                    <Condition Binding="{Binding IsMouseOver, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" Value="false"/>
                                    <Condition Binding="{Binding IsPressed, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" Value="false"/>
                                    <Condition Binding="{Binding IsEnabled, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" Value="true"/>
                                </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                                <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="templateRoot" Value="{StaticResource ComboBox.Static.Editable.Background}"/>
                                <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="templateRoot" Value="{StaticResource ComboBox.Static.Editable.Border}"/>
                                <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="splitBorder" Value="{StaticResource ComboBox.Static.Editable.Button.Background}"/>
                                <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="splitBorder" Value="{StaticResource ComboBox.Static.Editable.Button.Border}"/>
                            </MultiDataTrigger>
                            <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="true">
                                <Setter Property="Fill" TargetName="arrow" Value="{StaticResource ComboBox.MouseOver.Glyph}"/>
                            </Trigger>
                            <MultiDataTrigger>
                                <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                                    <Condition Binding="{Binding IsMouseOver, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" Value="true"/>
                                    <Condition Binding="{Binding IsEditable, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ComboBox}}}" Value="false"/>
                                </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                                <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="templateRoot" Value="{StaticResource ComboBox.MouseOver.Background}"/>
                                <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="templateRoot" Value="{StaticResource ComboBox.MouseOver.Border}"/>
                            </MultiDataTrigger>
                            <MultiDataTrigger>
                                <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                                    <Condition Binding="{Binding IsMouseOver, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" Value="true"/>
                                    <Condition Binding="{Binding IsEditable, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ComboBox}}}" Value="true"/>
                                </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                                <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="templateRoot" Value="{StaticResource ComboBox.MouseOver.Editable.Background}"/>
                                <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="templateRoot" Value="{StaticResource ComboBox.MouseOver.Editable.Border}"/>
                                <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="splitBorder" Value="{StaticResource ComboBox.MouseOver.Editable.Button.Background}"/>
                                <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="splitBorder" Value="{StaticResource ComboBox.MouseOver.Editable.Button.Border}"/>
                            </MultiDataTrigger>
                            <Trigger Property="IsPressed" Value="true">
                                <Setter Property="Fill" TargetName="arrow" Value="{StaticResource ComboBox.Pressed.Glyph}"/>
                            </Trigger>
                            <MultiDataTrigger>
                                <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                                    <Condition Binding="{Binding IsPressed, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" Value="true"/>
                                    <Condition Binding="{Binding IsEditable, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ComboBox}}}" Value="false"/>
                                </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                                <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="templateRoot" Value="{StaticResource ComboBox.Pressed.Background}"/>
                                <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="templateRoot" Value="{StaticResource ComboBox.Pressed.Border}"/>
                            </MultiDataTrigger>
                            <MultiDataTrigger>
                                <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                                    <Condition Binding="{Binding IsPressed, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" Value="true"/>
                                    <Condition Binding="{Binding IsEditable, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ComboBox}}}" Value="true"/>
                                </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                                <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="templateRoot" Value="{StaticResource ComboBox.Pressed.Editable.Background}"/>
                                <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="templateRoot" Value="{StaticResource ComboBox.Pressed.Editable.Border}"/>
                                <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="splitBorder" Value="{StaticResource ComboBox.Pressed.Editable.Button.Background}"/>
                                <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="splitBorder" Value="{StaticResource ComboBox.Pressed.Editable.Button.Border}"/>
                            </MultiDataTrigger>
                            <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="false">
                                <Setter Property="Fill" TargetName="arrow" Value="{StaticResource ComboBox.Disabled.Glyph}"/>
                            </Trigger>
                            <MultiDataTrigger>
                                <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                                    <Condition Binding="{Binding IsEnabled, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" Value="false"/>
                                    <Condition Binding="{Binding IsEditable, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ComboBox}}}" Value="false"/>
                                </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                                <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="templateRoot" Value="{StaticResource ComboBox.Disabled.Background}"/>
                                <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="templateRoot" Value="{StaticResource ComboBox.Disabled.Border}"/>
                            </MultiDataTrigger>
                            <MultiDataTrigger>
                                <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                                    <Condition Binding="{Binding IsEnabled, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" Value="false"/>
                                    <Condition Binding="{Binding IsEditable, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ComboBox}}}" Value="true"/>
                                </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                                <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="templateRoot" Value="{StaticResource ComboBox.Disabled.Editable.Background}"/>
                                <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="templateRoot" Value="{StaticResource ComboBox.Disabled.Editable.Border}"/>
                                <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="splitBorder" Value="{StaticResource ComboBox.Disabled.Editable.Button.Background}"/>
                                <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="splitBorder" Value="{StaticResource ComboBox.Disabled.Editable.Button.Border}"/>
                            </MultiDataTrigger>
                        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </ComboBox.Resources>
    <ComboBox.Template>
        <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ComboBox}"
                                 xmlns:Themes="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Windows.Themes;assembly=PresentationFramework.Aero2">
            <Grid x:Name="templateRoot" SnapsToDevicePixels="true">
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition MinWidth="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemParameters.VerticalScrollBarWidthKey}}" Width="0"/>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <Popup x:Name="PART_Popup" AllowsTransparency="true" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" IsOpen="{Binding IsDropDownOpen, Mode=TwoWay, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" Margin="1" PopupAnimation="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemParameters.ComboBoxPopupAnimationKey}}" Placement="Bottom">
                    <Themes:SystemDropShadowChrome x:Name="shadow" Color="Transparent" MaxHeight="{TemplateBinding MaxDropDownHeight}" MinWidth="{Binding ActualWidth, ElementName=templateRoot}">
                        <Border x:Name="dropDownBorder" BorderBrush="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.WindowFrameBrushKey}}" BorderThickness="1" Background="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.WindowBrushKey}}">
                            <ScrollViewer x:Name="DropDownScrollViewer">
                                <Grid x:Name="grid" RenderOptions.ClearTypeHint="Enabled">
                                    <Canvas x:Name="canvas" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="0">
                                        <Rectangle x:Name="opaqueRect" Fill="{Binding Background, ElementName=dropDownBorder}" Height="{Binding ActualHeight, ElementName=dropDownBorder}" Width="{Binding ActualWidth, ElementName=dropDownBorder}"/>
                                    </Canvas>
                                    <ItemsPresenter x:Name="ItemsPresenter" KeyboardNavigation.DirectionalNavigation="Contained" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}"/>
                                </Grid>
                            </ScrollViewer>
                        </Border>
                    </Themes:SystemDropShadowChrome>
                </Popup>
                <ToggleButton x:Name="toggleButton" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" IsChecked="{Binding IsDropDownOpen, Mode=TwoWay, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" Style="{StaticResource ComboBoxToggleButton}"/>
                <ContentPresenter x:Name="contentPresenter" ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding SelectionBoxItemTemplate}" ContentTemplateSelector="{TemplateBinding ItemTemplateSelector}" Content="{TemplateBinding SelectionBoxItem}" ContentStringFormat="{TemplateBinding SelectionBoxItemStringFormat}" HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" IsHitTestVisible="false" Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"/>
                <Rectangle x:Name="focusRect" Margin="2" SnapsToDevicePixels="true" Stroke="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlTextBrushKey}}"
                                   StrokeThickness="1" StrokeDashArray="1 2"
                                   Visibility="Collapsed"/>
            </Grid>
            <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="HasDropShadow" SourceName="PART_Popup" Value="true">
                    <Setter Property="Margin" TargetName="shadow" Value="0,0,5,5"/>
                    <Setter Property="Color" TargetName="shadow" Value="#71000000"/>
                </Trigger>
                <Trigger Property="HasItems" Value="false">
                    <Setter Property="Height" TargetName="dropDownBorder" Value="95"/>
                </Trigger>
                <Trigger Property="IsFocused" Value="True">
                    <Setter TargetName="focusRect" Property="Visibility" Value="Visible" />
                </Trigger>
                <MultiTrigger>
                    <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                        <Condition Property="IsGrouping" Value="true"/>
                        <Condition Property="VirtualizingPanel.IsVirtualizingWhenGrouping" Value="false"/>
                    </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                    <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll" Value="false"/>
                </MultiTrigger>
                <Trigger Property="ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll" SourceName="DropDownScrollViewer" Value="false">
                    <Setter Property="Canvas.Top" TargetName="opaqueRect" Value="{Binding VerticalOffset, ElementName=DropDownScrollViewer}"/>
                    <Setter Property="Canvas.Left" TargetName="opaqueRect" Value="{Binding HorizontalOffset, ElementName=DropDownScrollViewer}"/>
                </Trigger>
            </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
        </ControlTemplate>
    </ComboBox.Template>
</ComboBox>
```